# Can't delete breakpoint at flutter color in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I have a color which is set on a button and I had set a breakpoint there in order to see the button being created.

RaisedButton(

color: Colors.blue,   << breakpoint on this line

The color blue is shown as a blue rectangle in the breakpoint column, so when I right click on it to get the breakpoint context menu up, the menu doesn't appear.
To delete the breakpoint, must I delete the line and re-write it?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screenshot of a project instance in VS Code]

No, you don't need to delete and rewrite the line, instead,
you can see all your added breakpoints in Visual Studio Code from here and select/unselect them as needed.
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have it unselected in that list, but the list is very long and I want to focus on the active breakpoints, so I need to actually delete it.

Comment: Active breakpoints are marked red whereas inactive ones are marked grey, to delete it you can right click on your desired breakpoint and you'll find an option saying remove breakpoint which will do the work.

Comment: Yes, that delete option comes up for most breakpoints, but if the breakpoint is on a line of code setting a color it isn't presented. That's what I am enquiring about.